# Python template system like Smarty or Radius

Tags: python

Is there a Python template library similar to Smarty or Radius (Ruby's Movable Type-like template library) out there?

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, [Django.](http://www.djangobook.com) It has an excellent templating system.

It's slightly different from PHP, because of the following:

1. Variables and methods must be passed in to the template renderer.
2. Variables and methods are noted by `{{ braces }}`.
3. Tags (Django's version of PHP flow control statements), are denoted like `{% if x %}`, followed by a loop termination (like `{% endif %}`.
4. You can call functions directly from the template, but they will not accept any arguments.

There's a lot more, but I would highly recommend that you read the [Django book](http://www.djangobook.com).

Just one note: from personal experience, Django's ORM isn't very good for legacy database integration, so if you're looking for that, you might want to try [SQLalchemy](http://www.sqlalchemy.org/).

**EDIT:** Marcin had a good summary - Django's templating system, by design, encourages the separation of presentation and processing logic (i.e., loose coupling).

**EDIT 2:** There's also [mako](http://www.makotemplates.org/), which has a more PHP-like syntax.

Answer (score 1):

The python wiki entry on this topic is here: http://wiki.python.org/moin/Templating

The two well-known template systems other than Django are [cheetah](http://www.cheetahtemplate.org/) and [jinja](http://jinja.pocoo.org/).

[Django's templating system](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/templates/) is not especially powerful, *by design*, because that discourages any logic other than pure presentation logic in the templates. This is something that I value, having used JSP and ASP.

Jinja is pretty much a superset of Django's templates, except that if you wanted you could embed all of your view code in it ( I wouldn't ).

Cheetah looks rather more like JSP.

Any of these can be used with Django (the full stack framework), or you could use one of the microframeworks or "bundled" frameworks. See this wiki page: http://wiki.python.org/moin/WebFrameworks